# Optimizing query in mysql more efficient

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, query-performance

Please look at my query and execution plan I have added index in most of the table, but when I am joining it taking primary key and foreign key index. 
I am taking only 50 records.

it is taking 5-7 seconds.

How can I optimize this more efficient manner.

[image: mizi]

Comment: Please provide text, not pictures, and including SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables

Comment: Question would be more suited for https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I disagree.

Answer (score 0):

You can add index to column `po_id` in table `boxes` and also convert the derived table `claim_notes` into a sub-query

```
(SELECT MAX(claim_status_id) FROM claim_notes WHERE item_id = items.id) AS claim_status_id
```